# Kafka failing with: / by zero at kafka.network.Acceptor.run(SocketServer.scala:354)

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to run Kafka on windows (in azure cloud).
But it fails like every 2 days with hundred of / by zero and one IO exceptions below

```
[2018-06-12 09:00:23,457] ERROR Error while accepting connection (kafka.network.Acceptor)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at kafka.network.Acceptor.run(SocketServer.scala:354)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


[2018-06-12 09:00:23,457] ERROR Error while accepting connection 
(kafka.network.Acceptor)
 java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at kafka.network.Acceptor.run(SocketServer.scala:354)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


[2018-06-12 09:00:23,457] ERROR Error while accepting connection (kafka.network.Acceptor)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at kafka.network.Acceptor.run(SocketServer.scala:354)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

...........
...........


[2018-06-12 09:00:23,457] ERROR Failed to clean up log for __consumer_offsets-41 in dir C:\kafka\logs due to IOException (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\kafka\logs\__consumer_offsets-41\00000000000000000000.log.cleaned: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
at kafka.log.Cleaner.deleteCleanedFileIfExists$1(LogCleaner.scala:488)
at kafka.log.Cleaner.cleanSegments(LogCleaner.scala:493)
at kafka.log.Cleaner$$anonfun$doClean$4.apply(LogCleaner.scala:462)
at kafka.log.Cleaner$$anonfun$doClean$4.apply(LogCleaner.scala:461)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at kafka.log.Cleaner.doClean(LogCleaner.scala:461)
at kafka.log.Cleaner.clean(LogCleaner.scala:438)
at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.cleanOrSleep(LogCleaner.scala:305)
at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.doWork(LogCleaner.scala:291)
at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:82)
```

Removing all the logs and restarting Kafka resolves the issue (for 1-2 days)

Config:

- advertised.host.name = null
- advertised.listeners = null
- advertised.port = null
- alter.config.policy.class.name = null
- alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
- alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
- authorizer.class.name =
- auto.create.topics.enable = true
- auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
- background.threads = 10
- broker.id = 0
- broker.id.generation.enable = true
- broker.rack = null
- compression.type = producer
- connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
- controlled.shutdown.enable = true
- controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
- controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
- controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
- create.topic.policy.class.name = null
- default.replication.factor = 1
- delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
- delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
- delegation.token.master.key = null
- delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
- delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
- delete.topic.enable = true
- fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
- group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
- group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
- group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
- host.name =
- inter.broker.listener.name = null
- inter.broker.protocol.version = 1.1-IV0
- leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
- leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
- listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
- listeners = null
- log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
- log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
- log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
- log.cleaner.enable = true
- log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
- log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
- log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
- log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
- log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
- log.cleaner.threads = 1
- log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
- log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
- log.dirs = C:/kafka/logs
- log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
- log.flush.interval.ms = null
- log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
- log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
- log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
- log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
- log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
- log.message.format.version = 1.1-IV0
- log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
- log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
- log.preallocate = false
- log.retention.bytes = -1
- log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
- log.retention.hours = 72
- log.retention.minutes = null
- log.retention.ms = null
- log.roll.hours = 168
- log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
- log.roll.jitter.ms = null
- log.roll.ms = null
- log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
- log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
- max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
- max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
- max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
- message.max.bytes = 1000012
- metric.reporters = []
- metrics.num.samples = 2
- metrics.recording.level = INFO
- metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
- min.insync.replicas = 1
- num.io.threads = 12
- num.network.threads = 64
- num.partitions = 1
- num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
- num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
- num.replica.fetchers = 1
- offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
- offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
- offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
- offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
- offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
- offsets.retention.minutes = 1440
- offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
- offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
- offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
- offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
- password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
- password.encoder.iterations = 4096
- password.encoder.key.length = 128
- password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
- password.encoder.old.secret = null
- password.encoder.secret = null
- port = 9092
- principal.builder.class = null
- producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
- queued.max.request.bytes = -1
- queued.max.requests = 500
- quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
- quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
- quota.window.num = 11
- quota.window.size.seconds = 1
- replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
- replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
- replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
- replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
- replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
- replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
- replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
- replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
- replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
- replication.quota.window.num = 11
- replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
- request.timeout.ms = 30000
- reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
- sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
- sasl.jaas.config = null
- sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
- sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
- sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
- sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
- sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
- sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
- sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
- security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
- socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
- socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
- socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
- ssl.cipher.suites = []
- ssl.client.auth = none
- ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
- ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
- ssl.key.password = null
- ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
- ssl.keystore.location = null
- ssl.keystore.password = null
- ssl.keystore.type = JKS
- ssl.protocol = TLS
- ssl.provider = null
- ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
- ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
- ssl.truststore.location = null
- ssl.truststore.password = null
- ssl.truststore.type = JKS
- transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
- transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
- transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
- transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
- transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
- transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
- transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
- transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
- transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
- unclean.leader.election.enable = false
- zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181
- zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
- zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
- zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
- zookeeper.set.acl = false
- zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000

Comment: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` - if this is happening periodically then do you have some other software on the same machine as the broker that's interfering with the files? e.g. virus scan, backup process, etc?

Comment: i do not think so :( this is pretty standard Azure VM (which is backed up on VM/snapshot not OS/file level by Azure). No antivirus or related software. Failures are not consistent also, sometimes it works for a week or so.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of windows you're running, Defender might be enabled by default. If so, Try adding an exclusion on the c:\kafka directory.